# Mc bukkit heal plugin gives /usage instead of command

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm learning to create MC plugins and i'm trying to create a heal plugin. When I tested it, it gave the usage command instead of healing me.

```
package com.test.test;

// import and package extends JavaPlugin

public void onEnabled() {
    getLogger().info(getDescription().getName() + " has been enabled!!!!");
}

public void onDisabled() {
    getLogger().info(getDescription().getName() + " has been disabled!!!!");
}

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
    if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("full-life")) {
        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            if(args.length == 0){
                player.setHealth(player.getMaxHealth());
                player.sendMessage("You have been healed!");
            } else if(Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0] )!= null)  {
                Player target = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
                target.setHealth(target.getMaxHealth());
                player.sendMessage("The player" + target.getName() + "has been healed!");
                target.sendMessage("Player" + player.getName() + "has healed you!");
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Plugin.yml:

```
name: Test
main: com.test.test.Test
author: TheAsher
version: 1.0

commands:
  full-life:
    description: Get full lives
    usage: /<commmand> <player>
```

Comment: Could you be a little more clear on the result you were expecting and the result you actually got?

Comment: I tried out your plugin's code (including using identical package names and plugin.yml file) and everything seemed to work just fine. The method names are `onDisable()` and `onEnable()` by the way.

Comment: Thnx, i figured out what the problem was! Instead of importing the onCommand i imported command blocks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt import onCommand but Commandblocks...